# Do Java stream intermediate operations iterate the stream multiple times?

Tags: java, java-stream

Do java streams iterate a stream of values multiple times? For example, if we are filtering and then mapping, does the stream iterate once to filter and then iterate again to map? Or does it just filter and map each element as it iterates the stream once?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Definitely read the entire "Stream operations and pipelines" section, which pretty well answers this question.

Comment: Yes, I read them. I was confused on how the laziness worked which was answered below.

Comment: How it works is a totally different question. Yours was answered quite early with bullet point 5: "Consumable. The elements of a stream are only visited once during the life of a stream. Like an Iterator, a new stream must be generated to revisit the same elements of the source."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter, each intermediate operation is applied once to every item "flowing" through the stream. It is easy to verify yourself: simply add print statements in each step.

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5)
  .filter(x -> {
    System.out.println("Filtering " + x);
    return x < 4;
  })
  .map(x -> {
    System.out.println("Mapping " + x);
    return x * 2;
  })
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
Filtering 1
Mapping 1
2
Filtering 2
Mapping 2
4
Filtering 3
Mapping 3
6
Filtering 4
Filtering 5
```

"A stream" doesn't exist as a whole. A stream can be infinite. As long as nobody consumes the streams, no values are flowing through the stream. No consumers = no filtering, no mapping. The consumer of a stream is its terminal operation.

Only when the terminal operation is called, the stream takes the first element from its source and feeds it through its step one by one as necessary. Not all elements must arrive at the terminal operation (they could have been filtered out).

Some stream operations need to consume the full stream, before they can pass elements downstream, e.g. `sorted`. Sorting is impossible without knowing all the values. But most of the stream operations can operate on single elements and produce 0 or more new elements.

Comment: This is a helpful visualization! Though it does seem like it loops the list twice in a sense. Since filtering returns a stream and the map iterates that stream. According to the docs, "...filtering, mapping, and summing can be fused into a single pass on the data". How does this occur given the filter returns a stream of elements for map to operate on? Or is it such that it filter + maps each element at the same time?

Comment: filter produces an output element or it doesn't. This element is passed to map. Map always produces the next output element to be processed by whichever step comes next. But it doesn't really matter. (pseudo-code) `for(x:xs) { x = map(x); x = map(x); }` is equivalent to `for(x:xs) { x = map(x); } for (x:xs) { x = map(x); }`. What's expensive are the operations, not iterating.

Comment: I see, so essentially it executes each chained intermediate option on each element. Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: "How does this occur given the filter returns a stream of elements for map to operate on?"  A stream isn't a sequence of elements, it's a recipe to get a stream of elements.  If you just called `filter` by itself and not a `forEach` or anything afterwards, absolutely nothing would happen.  So the chained `map` produces a stream that maps elements as they're produced from the `filter` stream.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060617/869736